# Using the JQuery UI foreground color

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the UI-Lightness theme and I'm trying to figure out how to use the text color for my labels.  The color I'm interested in is the text found in the buttons, tabs, etc; it's the light blue.  I see that the color is defined in the ".ui-state-default" class but it also has border details and stuff I don't want.  Is there a way I can just use the color without the extra stuff?  I know I can hardcode the color into a new class but that won't help me if switch themes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of another way of doing this using jQuery while reading your comment. If you really find it a hassle you could add the following function at the start of all your pages:

```
var niceColor = $('.ui-state-default').css('color');

if(niceColor !== undefined)
{
    $('label').css('color', niceColor);
}
```

This will get the font color of the current `ui-state-default` class being used and give all your labels that colour. There is a gotcha though... You need to use something with the `ui-state-default` class on the page, otherwise nothing on the page has the class and therefore javascript cannot get the colour of it. That would mean you might have some labels not picking up the colour in a page where you're not using the `ui-state-default` class.

To get around this you could just stick a hidden element on each page like so ...

```
<input class="ui-state-default" style="display:none;" />
```

... just to be sure.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/E7Zza/1/

Comment: Thank you Spencer.  I like this idea.  It sure beats hard-coding the color in my CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just some labels that are unrelated to jQuery ui interactions, you may as well create a new css class and give that to the labels of your choice. The colour you're after is `#1C94C4`. If you decide to change to a different theme, you can simply change the colour specified in your class and the labels you've given the class to will be all be changed.

Additionally, if you do want to change a theme and don't want to change everything, you can configure a jQuery ui css file [here](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) on the left hand side. Or if you just want to edit certain characteristics of a pre-made theme (eg. change font colour for ui-lightness) you can do so there too by selecting **Galley > Edit** and specifying whatever changes you like... and download! :)

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I was hoping to avoid this because for testing, I switch themes back and forth often.  It makes sense to me that something like this should just be a default.